# Enable jQuery Intellisense without referencing local jQuery (or in each file) in VS2010

Tags: jquery, visual-studio-2010, intellisense, javascript-intellisense

So I've been looking at jQuery and thought it would be nice to have the vsdoc's for the project I'm working on.

The problem is all of the methods to enable Intellisense for the project are not suitable.

I need to be able to enable IntelliSense without referencing the vsdoc in each file and we also currently use the jQuery CDN so need an option without modifying any of the code itself, is there any options or anything that allow me to add external jsdoc's?

So to clarify, I'm looking for a method of enabling jQuery IntelliSense without modifying my VS2010 project, hopefully through VS2010 options or something.

Answer (score 3):

If you put `jquery-vsdoc.js` besides your `jquery.js`, just the reference to `jquery.js` is enough to have IntelliSense running. And it is probably valid not only for jquery but for other files with -vsdoc.js (maybe .debug.js too). [VS2008 SP1 Hotfix to Support "-vsdoc.js" IntelliSense Doc Files](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdevtools/archive/2008/11/07/hotfix-to-enable-vsdoc-js-intellisense-doc-files-is-now-available.aspx). The article is about VS2008 and I write about VS2010 but I suppose statements are valid (I have tried only `jquery-vsdoc.js`). This technique works in .aspx but not in .html.

You can also use a master page see [JScript IntelliSense FAQ](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdevtools/archive/2008/11/18/jscript-intellisense-faq.aspx).

Comment: Normally I'd like this method, but the problem we have is it's a huge project and just isn't practical with how we're running it unfortunately.

As it stands I've found no solution suitable, it's a shame there is no option to globally enable stuff like this for IntelliSense.

Comment: If you have <script src="jquery.js"></script> on .aspx page to add jquery-vsdoc.js to the same folder as jquery.js  (neither script tag nor reference) is enough to have IntelliSese working. What you need more?

Comment: Because the script isn't being referenced, it's only referenced if and when required by checking some functions, so it is never directly on the page. As I said before, it's just not a practical solution for what I require :)

Answer (score 3):

Go to Tools-Options-Text Editor-Javascript-Intellisense-References and place a reference to the intellisense files for the version of jquery you are using in the Implicit Web group.

[image]

To get the latest jquery files with intellisense use the nuget package installer which by default will create a scripts folder and place the jquery version.js, the min.js and intellisense.js files into... from there you can copy them to the location most of the Microsoft references are placed which is typically

install-package jquery in the package manager console.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\JavaScript\References
```

Comment: the screenshot revealing the secret `~/Scripts/_references.js` magic location is awesome, thanks a ton.

Comment: Hm dont have JavaScript under Text Editor in my Visual Studio 2010. that is pretty annoying

Comment: I have a JScript under Text Editor, but not Intellisense under JScript.  What am I missing?

Comment: Maybe this screenshot is for Visual Studio 2012? Just guessing because of the path mentioning "Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0". Nice tip anyway, but not for us, VS2010 users, like the OP.